# UIBarButtonItem doesn't show up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Why doesn't this show up? I tried simulator 5.1 and 6.0. Have something changed lately?

```
UIBarButtonItem* rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl target:self action:@selector(openGasMileage)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As default curl image is not exist in >= ios5 sdk, you have to use your own image:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *) rightBarButtonItem {
    if (_rightBarButtonItem == nil) {
    UIButton *rightButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    [rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(own) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
    }
return _rightBarButtonItem;
}

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightBarButtonItem;
```

Also see this: [curl item](http://blog.shuningbian.net/2011/01/ios-toolbar-pagecurl-icon.html)